# PIC32 MX230F064B USB POWERED

Tags: microcontroller, pic, usb

I made a board that can power a [PIC32MX230F064B](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC32MX230F064B) through a regulated power supply at my college lab. Now I want to power the circuit through USB-A (USB-A to USB-A wire, so I can power it with powerbanks or with my computer). The chip works at 3.3V. I did a little bit of research and USB outputs 5V. I have some doubts in regard to USB always outputting 5V in standard conditions. I also don't know if I need some kind of logical circuit which negotiates the current output that USB gives. I don't know either if it's better to use a regulator or a resistance to go from 5V to 3.3V.

Comment: What are current requirements of your circuit? And yes, USB VCC has 5V DC whenever it is plugged to host.

Comment: @Swanand i dont know

Comment: You can measure it for your existing circuit which is powered through regular supply... Concern is USB usually provides 1.2A, if your requirement is more then your circuit will not work... Otherwise no problem... All you need is a Level Shifter

Comment: I was thinking of a regulator to go from 5v to 3.3v. I'm not an electrical engineer or electronical, so I don't know all the terms.

Comment: Yes.. It Will work!

Comment: Please define your problem and ask a question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Readers shouldn't have to ask questions for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you are after with a regulator, a couple of capacitors, and two diodes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8MAJB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D1 and D2 act as a power "OR" gate - the power supply with the highest voltage wins and supplies the power to the regulator. The regulator then reduces that power (whatever it is - as long as it is above 3.3V + the regulator's *dropout voltage*) down to 3.3V to power the chip.

The diodes should have a low forward voltage drop (Schottky are good for that) and the sum of the drop + regulated voltages must be below 4.75V:

\$(V_{D1} + V_{DROP} + 3.3) < 4.75\$

This is to ensure that the voltage at the input to the regulator when powered from USB (which can be as low as 4.75V and still be within specifications) is more than 3.3V plus the regulator dropout voltage. The lower the dropout voltage, and the lower the diode forward voltage drop, the easier your task will be.

USB is guaranteed to provide you (initially) with 100mA of current capacity. You request more by specifying the requirements of your circuit in your USB device descriptor within the USB stack you are using (e.g., Harmony or MLA).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a 5v to 3.3v voltage regulator such as [LM3940](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/78785.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiD54ON4MfQAhULvI8KHdjGCDQQFgiBATAQ&usg=AFQjCNH2Rhn826m8I532QsvRO15Z_E3cBQ&sig2=bfGm8FSa-NnK2niFulTnhw) from National Semiconductor. It should have enough info and schematic example from the datasheet.

Its recommended to use a voltage regulator over resistance to ensure regulated power for your microcontroller operation